# setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem not firing

Tags: ipad, ios6, uisplitviewcontroller

I am updating my iPad app and I've got a list of options in the table of the split view controller, but it's not firing the setDetalItem is not firing. This will not be ported to the iPhone because of the form-factor (screen is too small).

From the appDelegate class:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

    UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[0];
    JSLMasterViewController *controller = (JSLMasterViewController *)masterNavigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    return YES;   
}
```

from the masterViewController:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    JSLDetailViewController *detailView = self.detailViewController;
    detailView.telegram = indexPath.row;

    NSLog(@"Did Fire 1");

}
```

And from my detailViewController:

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    NSLog(@"Did Fire 2");

    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

    // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }

    if (self.masterPopoverController != nil) {
        [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

    }

}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {
        //self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"timeStamp"] description];

        NSArray *mainQuestion = [self mainQuestionArray];
        NSArray *subQuestion = [self subQuestionArray];
        questionTitle.text = mainQuestion[telegram];
        subQuestionOne.text = subQuestion[telegram][0];
        subQuestionTwo.text = subQuestion[telegram][1];
    }

}
```

I understand that I may need to create an instance of the detailViewController in the appDelegate, but I am unsure as to how to do this. Most of the tutorials I have found build a split view from scratch or seem to be using an older version of the mechanism. Any tips you can give me would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set detailView.detailItem in order for the `- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem` to fire.

In the MasterViewController.m detailViewController is usually something like:

```
self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
```

and then in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        NSYourCoolObject *object = _YourObjectArray[indexPath.row];
        self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
}
```

Comment: The boiler plate Master-Detail  in xcode is a good example.  Just hit File - New - Project and select Master-Detail Application.

Comment: I was using the boilerplate; I hadn't edited it much, but somewhere the code to fire it got lost. Thank you for your help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that, in iOS6, one needs to call, "setDetailItem" directly. You can pass objects here, although it's not necessarily what you would think. I added the following code to didSelectItemAtIndexPath:

```
[detailView setDetailItem:indexPath];
```

This fired the update to the MasterViewController and life is good.